# An error when signin with for-your-eyes only

Tags: gnupg

On Ubuntu, a line `sudo gpg -r myself --for-your-eyes-only  --digest-algo SHA512  --clearsign ~/testing`

produces a sign document, but then the first option for opening it becomes `Open with Import Key`. When I try that, it fails with `Import failes. Keys found but not imported`.
What is that Import Keys thing, and why does it fail?
P.S.
The signed file opens ok in gedit.

Comment: `sudo` together with `gpg` should always come together with an explanation why you need it. I don't really get your question, please provide the full commands you used together with full output of GnuPG (with other words, everything not sensitive).

Comment: Actually, there's nothing more to provide, I think; the file got clearsigned, and everything else went as usual.

Comment: "but then the first option for opening it becomes": I don't understand this paragraph _at all_. Providing the command resulting in the message you quoted would probably help _a lot_.

Comment: I run the line. A signed file is created. I right-click on that file and get a menu. The first item on that menu is `Open with Import Keys`. If I create a signed file with `gpg`, but without `--for-your-eyes-only`, the first item on the menu is just `open` or `open with gedit`. Does that clarify anything?